# Integration Google Analytics using Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm integrating google analytics using Javascript. But it is okay to authroize using client_id, scope.
After that, tried to load google analytics data.

But it says that it is 'insufficient_scope'. 
The reference url is https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js
I hope you provide the best solutions to me.

I've configured google developer account. I've set *Oauth consent screen* for scope.
It it shows yellow warning card and the text is that "Because you've added a sensitive scope, your consent screen requires verification by Google before it's published.".

```
window.gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get({
 'ids': 'ga:' + 'id',
 'start-date': '7daysAgo',
 'end-date': 'today',
 'metrics': 'ga:sessions'
})
```

Comment: The yellow warning you mentioned is fine for now, it just means publishing may take slightly longer (which you don't need for development purposes). Which scope are you using when requesting the access code prior to the token?

Comment: @junvar The scope for requesting to authorize, I've used "./auth/analytics.readonly" on google developer account.
But I didn't use the access token from that api response.


**
api.auth.authorize(authData, function(response))
**

Comment: @junvar, after calling google api authorization, I've called the api to load google analytics data.
But the api response data has 403 error - 
The error message is "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes." Do you have any idea for this problem?

Comment: Can you try with the full scope string `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'`?

Comment: @junvar Yup, I've used that scope.
```scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']```

Comment: @junvar
```"{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."}],"code":403,"message":"Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."}}"```



It is body error message from api response(```gapi.client.load('analytics', 'v3')```)